# Calculating inline width with PHP breaks image carousel (Flickity)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, flickity

I'm using [Flickity](https://flickity.metafizzy.co) to implement a `asNavFor` slider, [like so](https://codepen.io/zoostudios/pen/NWWPPJP).

I've integrated this into WordPress and [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/). Using the repeater field, admin have the ability to create unlimited slides. This means I have to define the width for each `.nav-item` inline vs an external stylesheet.

Here's how it looks in PHP:

```
<div class="nav-item" style="width:<?= (100 / count(get_field('tabs_builder')) ); ?>%"><span>Slide One</span></div>
```

The PHP here is counting how many ACF slides exist and then divide it by 100. In my example, this would give an inline width of 20%.

This works well in modern browsers. Here's how it looks:

[image: Flickity asNavFor]

However, in IE11 sometimes it displays like this:

[image: Flickity asNavFor IE11]

When displaying incorrectly the inline style width for `.nav-item` is correct and displays 20%. `.flickity-viewport` height is incorrect at 40px. `transform: translateX(7.6%)` should be 0%.

I can't replicate the bug using this [CodePen debug version](https://cdpn.io/zoostudios/debug/NWWPPJP/mWkoNLjzZDjA).

Could this be down to the page not loading the PHP in time to calculate the width? What would be an alternative solution to calculating the nav items width?

Here's a [live version](https://www.financebi.com/finance-transformation/) of the site.

Comment: "Could this be down to the page not loading the PHP in time to calculate the width?" PHP runs on the server, not in your browser, so by the time the page starts loading the PHP execution is complete.

Comment: I thought this might be the case. Any ideas why this is only happening in an older browser though? What would be a solution to fix this?

Comment: "Sometimes it works correctly, but a lot of the time the .flickity-viewport height and width is incorrect." Incorrect in what way? What is the width value when it is incorrect?

Comment: When displaying incorrectly the inline style width for `.nav-item` is correct and displays 20%.  `.flickity-viewport` height is incorrect at 40px. `transform: translateX(7.6%)` should be 0%.

Comment: As I seen the problem is on the parent element (flickity-slider): it has transform: translateX(6.62%); isntead of transform: translateX(0%); and probably because of this the positioning is wrong on each element (left: 17.32%, 34,62%...).